# how to prevent system font-size changing effects to nativescript-angular android application

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

The problem is when i adjusted the android device system font-size, my 
user application's font-sizes are changing to device system font-size
how to prevent it

Comment: That's expected behaviour as the default unit system is scaled pixel. If you simply mention the font size in px (`font-size: 20px`), you will be able to prevent the auto scaling.

Comment: I tried to apply font-size:20px but not supported  NativeScript does not in fact use any units of measurement, and all lengths are expressed in numbers as per nativescript document

Comment: No, that's not true. Android supports font size in pixel unit, but at least I never used it as I would prefer scaled pixel and auto scaling to work. Let me try it on my end.

Comment: I was looking at part of the source code where they seem intended to support font size in pixels. But the parsing logic of font size never seems to allow that. But I may have an override, will post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default unit for font size in Android is Scaled Pixels, setting it to DIP or PX will prevent auto scaling.

**Tested against v6.0**

```
import { isAndroid } from 'tns-core-modules/platform';
import { TextBase } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/text-base/text-base';

declare var android; // required if tns-platform-declarations is not installed

if (isAndroid) {
    TextBase.prototype[require("tns-core-modules/ui/text-base/text-base-common").fontSizeProperty.setNative] = function (value) {
        if (!this.formattedText || (typeof value !== "number")) {
            if (typeof value === "number") {
                this.nativeTextViewProtected.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, value);
            }
            else {
                this.nativeTextViewProtected.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, value.nativeSize);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Since you are using Angular, you may place this code in `main.ts` Or in app module.

Comment: Has anyone figured this out for {N} 7+?  Replacing 'tns-core-modules' with '@nativescript/core' is not sufficient and yields:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'setNative' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

For NativeScript 7+, I elected to modify @nativescript/core/ui/text-base/index.android.js directly and use patch-package to manage the change, as I use patch-package for a handful of plugins I had to migrate myself.  Here's the patch, effectively a one-line change:

```
--- a/node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/text-base/index.android.js
+++ b/node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/text-base/index.android.js
@@ -274,7 +274,10 @@ export class TextBase extends TextBaseCommon {
     [fontSizeProperty.setNative](value) {
         if (!this.formattedText || typeof value !== 'number') {
             if (typeof value === 'number') {
-                this.nativeTextViewProtected.setTextSize(value);
+                // Override font scaling so that app styling remains consistent regardless of system font size. 
+                // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57181909/how-to-prevent-system-font-size-changing-effects-to-nativescript-angular-android
+                this.nativeTextViewProtected.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, value);  
+                // this.nativeTextViewProtected.setTextSize(value);
             }
             else {
                 this.nativeTextViewProtected.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, value.nativeSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching for solution, in NativeScript 8.5 (possibly 8+) this works:

in main.ts :

```
import { AndroidApplication, Application, CoreTypes, TextBase, fontSizeProperty, isAndroid, isIOS } from '@nativescript/core'

...
if (Application.android) {
  TextBase.prototype[fontSizeProperty.setNative] =
   function (value) {
    if (!this.formattedText || (typeof value !== "number")) {
        if (typeof value === "number") {
            this.nativeTextViewProtected.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, value);
        }
        else {
            this.nativeTextViewProtected.setTextSize(android.util.TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, value.nativeSize);
        }
    }
   }
}
```